# Pyomo - How to consider all scenarios in the objective function within the ReferenceModel?

Tags: pyomo

I am facing a problem in defining the objective function shown in Figure: [Objective Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2WdX.jpg).

In here, *p_n = 1/#Scenarios* and *W-n: Final Wealth in Scenario n*. Scenarios are equiprobable, so *p_n* is known in advance.

The problem is: How can I define the sum of the cross-product of *p_n* and *W_n* over EVERY scenario, if the Deterministic ReferenceModel considers only one scenario? In other terms, given that the set of scenarios is added only after having defined the objective function in the deterministic model, how can I consider all the scenarios?

Moreover, I have to count the number of times in which the Final Wealth is lower than the Target Wealth, in a given pre-specified stage. How can I set the counter, if the Deterministic ReferenceModel considers just one scenario?

I am a new Pyomo user, and a quantitative finance student with no much knowledge about Operation Research, so I apologize in advance if the questions are obvious or silly.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Roberto. 
I think that you should ask more precise question and a forum as [OR in SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/)

From my perspective you're having a mistake. If you're trying to model an Stochastic Programming model, you need to have defined all parameter from each scenario from the scenario tree, since each parameterization depends upon it. In `Pyomo` you can parameterize the information of all scenarios (params, vars, etc) from a deterministic (one scenario) problem [see here](https://pysp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysp.html#overview-of-modeling-components-and-processes).

Comment: Hi pybeginner! Thanks for your comment! My problem dealt with the specification of one parameter for the ReferenceModel, where that param would be defined by the optimization. However, I have modified my objective function, remembering that the derivatives of the sum of some functions is equal to the  sum of the derivative of those functions. By modifying the objective function, I was able to define my problem.

Comment: Great. That would be nice if you answer your own problem for any further questions in SO.